# Textures don't render

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I have the following code in which I'm attempting to render first a background, then some items on top of them. The only thing that comes out is the background.

---

Textures is a vector of a class I made, which basically just holds an `SDL_Texture*` and an `SDL_Rect*`. The textures aren't `NULL`, the SDL_Rect positioning is on the screen, I'm not sure why they aren't showing up.

```
//Clear screen
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, background, NULL, NULL); //Render background

for (auto texture : textures) {
    if (texture.getXPos() && texture.getYPos()) { //Position, if applicable
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture.getTexture(), NULL, texture.getRect());
    }
    else {
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture.getTexture(), NULL, NULL);
    }
}

//Update screen
SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Stupid error: When I was using `SDL_Surface` I would set the w and h of the `SDL_Rect` to 0, which evidently isn't how it's supposed to work with `SDL_Texture`.

Comment: It's not stupid, it's just that SDL_RenderCopy's behavior does not match SDL_BlitSurface's behavior though the interface seems similar.  It's not an obvious change, so this is a common bug for those who used SDL 1.2.